# How to optimize three consecutive str.replace() calls?

Tags: python, replace

```
expr='9subtract5equal4'

expr = expr.replace('subtract', '-')
expr = expr.replace('plus', '+')
expr = expr.replace('equal', '==')
```

I feel the last three lines code are very ugly, so I've tried to optimize using `map` and other functional programming functions. But I did't find a good way to achieve that. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does 'optimize' mean? Run faster? Use less characters? Use less run-time memory?

Comment: [Codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Perhaps maintain a dictionary of replacements.

Comment: @usr2564301 I want to use less characters.

Comment: Hmmm, now I think this is a quite stupid question. I'm so sorry for that..

Comment: @Georgy Thank you very much, that's exactly what I want! And sorry for my poor search ability...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do:

```
expr = expr.replace('subtract', '-').replace('plus', '+').replace('equal', '==')
```

Or, you could loop through a `dict`ionary of replacements:

```
replace = {'subtract': '-', 'plus': '+', 'equal': '='}
for word in replace:
    expr = expr.replace(word, replace[word])
```

Comment: you could also use regex define a lambda: "repl = lambda x: expr[x.group(0)]" then call "re.sub('subtract|equal', string="9subtract5equal4", repl=repl)" where expr is a dict with your replacements

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
def replace_all(text, dic):
  for i, j in dic.items():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
  return text

s = '9subtract5equal4'

d = {
  'subtract': '-',
  'plus': '+',
  'equal': '==',
}

s = replace_all(s, d)
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is the code is fine but you could operate directly on the return value at each step:

```
expr='9subtract5equal4'

expr = expr.replace('subtract', '-') \
    .replace('plus', '+') \
    .replace('equal', '==')
```

Or even

```
expr = '9subtract5equal4' \
    .replace('subtract', '-') \
    .replace('plus', '+') \
    .replace('equal', '==')
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a dictionary that maps from operand name to the symbol:

   ```
   ops = {'subtract':'-', 'add':'+', 'equal':'=='}
   ```

   You can make it as long as you want, which clearly is an optimisation – adding more operands is extremely easy and does not need any further modification.
2. Loop over your expression using a list comprehension:

   ```
   [x if x.isdigit() else ops[x] for x in re.findall(r'\d+|[a-z]+',expr)]
   ```

   This uses a regex to separate digits and operands, so `import re` at the start. The regex returns

   ```
   ['9', 'subtract', '5', 'equal', '4']
   ```

   and the list comprehension replaces not-digit strings with the items from the dictionary.

Result:

```
['9', '-', '5', '==', '4']
```

so you'd use

```
expr = ''.join([x if x.isdigit() else ops[x] for x in re.findall(r'\d+|[a-z]+',expr)])
```

to get your output

```
'9-5==4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would write it the way you wrote it, but if you want to do it "functionally" you probably need to use `functools.reduce`, as you need to "reduce" a list of substitutions into a single result:

```py
import functools

expr = '9subtract5equal4'

# a list of our replacements, as pairs
REPLACEMENTS = [
    ('subtract', '-'),
    ('plus', '+'),
    ('equal', '=='),
]

result = functools.reduce(
    lambda word, old_new: word.replace(old_new[0], old_new[1]),
    REPLACEMENTS,
    expr
)
```

Here we just "accumulate" the results of the lambda function, which takes the last "accumulated" word and a substitution pair, and calls `.replace()` to get the next "accumulated" word.

But really this is not a Pythonic way to solve this problem (there is a reason why `reduce` got shoved into `functools` in Python 3), and your original approach is better.